# How to redirect to servlet when we have multiple buttons

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have 2 textboxes and 3 buttons and each button has specific action i.e. insert, update, delete.
But how to redirect it when specific button click ?
because i have used it in one form tag.

so what will it do when any button click ?
how it will get the action name ?

code :

```
<form action="Doaction" method="post">

First Name : <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<br> 
Last Name : <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>


<input type="button" value="Insert">



<input type="button" value="Update">



<input type="button" value="Delete">
</form>
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in form : give name to buttons

```
First Name : <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<br> 
Last Name : <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>


<input type="button" value="Insert" name="button">



<input type="button" value="Update" name="button">



<input type="button" value="Delete" name="button">
</form>

String button_param = request.getParameter("button");
RequestDispatcher rd = null;

if(button_param .equals("Insert")
{
rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("InsertServlet");
}
else if(button_param .equals("Update"))
{
rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("UpdateServlet");
}
else if(button_param .equals("Delete"))
{
rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("DeleteServlet");
}

rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: yes i have done something like that, i have posted my answer.

Comment: @user2659972 : so your problem is solved , right?? cool , then accept your answer so that people stop answering it

Comment: yes but i can't accept it till 2 days, it's stckoverflow's rule.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a common javascript function like submitForm('pass your action').
Here you can see that function has a parameter. you have to pass action based your requirement 
for example :

```
<input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="submitForm('InsertURL');"> 
<input type="button" value="Update" onclick="submitForm('UpdateURL');">
```

Action function body like :

```
function submitForm(action){
     //send Ajax Request to server...using action 
}
```

Comment: i have used below technique and it works. BTW thanx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have solved it.

I have given a common name to each button and in servlet i have first checked that from which button action call then as per it i have used if condition and inside it's block i have make a related code.

code :

```
<form action="Doreg" method="post">

First Name : <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<br> 
Last Name : <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Insert" name="kb">
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="kb">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="kb">

</form>
```

java code :

```
String fname =request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname =request.getParameter("lname");
        String f = request.getParameter("kb");


        if (f.equals("Insert"))
        {
            obj.connect();
            String query ="insert into user(firstname,lastname) values('"+fname+"','"+lname+"')";

            obj.passquery(query);
        }

        else if(f.equals("Delete"))
        {
            obj.connect();
            String query ="delete user where firstname='"+fname+"' OR lastname='"+lname+"'";

            obj.passquery(query);
        }
```